# Can I authorize on JIRA with 2-legged OAuth?

Tags: oauth, jira, jira-rest-api

I tried following https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/APPLINKS050/OAuth+security+for+application+links to enable 2-legged OAuth against my JIRA (7.4.2) instance (where I'm an admin), but I can't seem to be able to find/edit the fields mentioned.

I used the docker image found at https://hub.docker.com/r/cptactionhank/atlassian-jira

Has the possibility been removed at some point? If yes, has a reason been stated? If no, how can I enable it?

Comment: Consider asking your JIRA administrator to check permissions on the account that you are using to get this working. Any time I find that fields or options are not present on JIRA, it's a permissions issue.

Comment: @RobKielty I downloaded and fired up a JIRA 7.4.2 instance on my local machine to test the JIRA OAuth locally before going to work on the "actual" JIRA instance. However I (as an admin on "my" JIRA) couldn't find any way  to enable 2-legged. That's what my question is, updated it now to make that clear.

Comment: I've run thru simple setup using the docker image.  I note that there is an "Application Links" option is present under *Administration* > INTEGRATIONS > Application Links. Can you set up the app link there and see if the referenced docs start to make sense? Actually this feels like it could be the answer. I'll leave it as a comment though just in case ;)